# String object to number Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Lets say, I have a string like "150 test".
How can I convert this string to a number with the value of 150?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Typescript supports type casting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), which you will need in your case if you have your variable types declared.

You simply just want to achieve something like this in JS.

```
var result = parseInt("125 test");
// result is 125
```

So, it's possible to cast like follows in typescript,

```
let msg: String = "125 test";

// If 'msg' is 'String', cast it to 'string' since 'parseInt' argument only accepts 'string'.
let result: Number = parseInt(<string>msg);
// result is 125
```

This will then be transpiled into **js**, like;

```
var msg = "125 test";
var result = parseInt(msg);
```

Comment: Adding type declarations to variables which are immediately assigned is unnecessary, because typescript automatically add the type to the variable under the hood.

Comment: Using box types like String and Number is bad practice. Check out typescript official do's and don'ts: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html

Comment: @BalázsTakács That's not the case here. Editors or linters are picky about the type definitions in typescript. At least I show him how he can handle them

Comment: Actually, that is considered bad practice because of the case like `parseInt` above. If OP in fact develops his own codebase with typescript and use boxed types, I don't see why not.

Answer (score 5):

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

> An integer number parsed from the given string. If the first character cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned.

You can use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) which will try to parse the string to number until it gets a non-digit character.

```js
var str = "150 test";
console.log(parseInt(str))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use numbers [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt) method.

```js
console.log( Number.parseInt('150 test') );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code snippet:

```
let str = "150 test";
let result = Number(str.split(" ")[0])
```